# Parse author tag using XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

In one of my projects that i'm working off i'm trying to parse all feeds from an atom xml as this below.

```xml
<entry>
  <id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-4512083858574973357.post-3473864646179740942</id>
  <published>2015-09-14T09:28:00.000+03:00</published>
  <updated>2015-09-14T15:30:18.832+03:00</updated>
  <title type="text">Mytitle</title>
  <content>Hello</content>
  <author>
     <name>Author name</name>
     <uri>URI HERE</uri>
     <email>EMAIL HERE</email>
     <gd:image rel="" width="32" height="32" src="" />
  </author>
```

I can get all tags using the following code but i have no idea how to parse the name of the author.

```java
 private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException, ParseException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "entry");
    String id = null;
    String title = null;
    Uri image = null;
    String link = null;
    String content = null;
    String description;
    String author = null;
    String shortDescription = null;
    ArrayList tags= new ArrayList<>();;
    long publishedOn = 0;

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        switch (name) {
            case "id":
                id = readTag(parser, TAG_ID);
                break;
            case "title":
                title = readTag(parser, TAG_TITLE);
                break;
            case "link":
                link = readTag(parser, TAG_LINK);
                break;
            case "author":
                //**************************************************** 
                CANT GET THE NAME OF THE AUTHOR HERE
                //****************************************************
                 break;
            case "category": {
                String tempLink = readTag(parser, TAGS);
                if (tempLink != null) {
                    tags.add(tempLink);
                }
                break;
            }
            case "content": {
                String tempLink = readTag(parser, TAG_CONTENT);
                if (tempLink != null) {
                    content = tempLink;
                    image = Uri.parse(pullImageLink(content));
                    description = Html.fromHtml(content.replaceAll("<img.+?>", "")).toString().trim();
                    if (description.length() > 0) {
                        int descrLength = description.length();
                        if (descrLength > 250) {
                            shortDescription = description.substring(0, 250);
                        } else {
                            shortDescription = description.substring(0, descrLength);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case "published":
                publishedOn = getParsedDate(readTag(parser, TAG_PUBLISHED));
                break;
            default:
                skip(parser);
                break;
        }
    }
    assert image != null;
    return new Entry(id, title, image.toString(), link, content, shortDescription, publishedOn,tags, author);
}
```